# Tooltip not showing on d3.js area graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to show a tooltip when hovering over my d3.js area graph. I'm not seeing the tooltip appear.

I've looked at the mousemove event and mouseout and it looks correct. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Link to JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j2vk8txh/

```
                source.selectAll(".area")
                .style("opacity", 1) // Set the initial opacity to 1
                .style("stroke", "none") // Add a stroke
                .on("mousemove", function (d) {
                    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]);
                    var bisect = d3.bisector(function (d) { return d.date; }).left;
                    var i = bisect(d.values, x0, 1);
                    var d0 = d.values[i - 1];
                    var d1 = d.values[i];
                    var d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;

                    d3.select(this)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(50)
                        .style("opacity", 0.85);

                    // Show tooltip
                    tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0.9);
                    tooltip.html("X: " + d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date) + "<br/>Y: " + d.kW)
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                })
                .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(50)
                        .style("opacity", 1);

                    // Hide tooltip
                    tooltip.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

`source` is already your `<G>` elements with class `area`. When you do `source.selectAll(".area")` you are trying to select elements with a class `area` inside the `<G>`. Just do:

```
source.style("opacity", 1)
    .etc...
```